# mod_rewrite - Rules don't work together, but work fine on their own

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Thanks in advance.

What I am trying to do is rewrite anything with the word "assets" and simply tack on the /projects/ to the beginning. Then rewrite everything else to my index.php file.

So,
/phantom-hearts/assets/pdf/cabbot-story.pdf
/allyson-darke/assets/jpg/image1.jpg

becomes
/projects/phantom-hearts/assets/pdf/cabbot-story.pdf
/projects/allyson-darke/assets/jpg/image1.jpg

Then, rewrite everything else to my index.php file.

Here is my .htaccess file

Code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#rewrite project assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets$
RewriteRule (.*)/assets(.*) projects/$1/assets$2 [L]

#rewrite everything else
RewriteRule .*          index.php/$0    [PT,L,NC]
```

Both of these rules work fine on their own and this file works in a few htaccess online testers I've tried, but when I try them on my localhost, I get Internal Server Errors.

Any ideas? What am I missing? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#rewrite project assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets
RewriteRule (.*)/assets(.*) projects/$1/assets$2 [L]

#rewrite everything else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L,NC]
```

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: Well, this is strange. The solution works on my localhost. When I move it to godaddy, I have to use index.php?/$0 AND the assets rewrite is sending it to the index.php.

Comment: There is something different on GoDaddy then. May be `projects/$1/assets$2` doesn't find a valid file. Try `/projects/$1/assets$2`

Comment: Got it. Lost the ! before assets. For anyone who wants it, the final code was: `RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#rewrite project assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /assets
RewriteRule (.*)/assets(.*) /projects/$1/assets$2 [L]

#rewrite everything else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L,NC] `